# Как сделать запрос с группировкой в связных моделей через промежуточную таблицу?

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть две модели - User и Project и связная модель которая их объединяет ProjectUser
Выборка всех проектов где есть пользователь организована в модели User:

```
 public function getProjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class, ['id' => 'fk_project_id'])
            ->viaTable(ProjectsUsers::tableName(), ['fk_user_id' => 'id'])
            ->orderBy('title');
    }
```

Выборка всех пользователей в проекте организована:

```
 public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, ['id' => 'fk_user_id'])
            ->viaTable(ProjectsUsers::tableName(), ['fk_project_id' => 'id'])
    }
```

Есть особенность, в таблице Projects, есть поля `fk_owner_id, fk_owner_id2, fk_owner_id3`, куда назначаются владельцы (Users) по `id`

Мне нужно получить выборку всех проектов где пользователь является одним из владельцем или участником. На sql я делаю так(пример с id User = 20):

```
        select projects.* FROM projects
        left join projectsusers on projectsusers.fk_user_id = 20
        where projects.fk_owner_id like 20
        or projects.fk_owner_id2 like 20
        or projects.fk_owner_id3 like 20
        group by projects.title
```

> Как мне организовать правильно запрос внутри модели User ?

Пробовал вот так:

```
public function getAllProjects(){
        $projects = Project::find()
        ->leftJoin('projectsusers','projectsusers.fk_user_id ='.$this->id)
        ->orWhere(['fk_owner_id' => $this->id])
        ->orWhere(['fk_owner_id2' => $this->id])
        ->orWhere(['fk_owner_id3' => $this->id])
        ->groupBy('projects.title')
        ->orderBy('projects.title')
        ->all();
        return $projects;
    }
```

, но это не дает результата.

Answer (score 0):

Решено так:

```
$query = Project::find()
            ->with('fkOwner')
            ->with('fkOwner2')
            ->with('fkOwner3')
            ->join(
            'join',
            ProjectsUsers::tableName(),
            ProjectsUsers::tableName().'.fk_project_id = '.Projects::tableName().'.id')
            ->where(ProjectsUsers::tableName().'.fk_user_id = '.$this->id)
            ->orWhere(['or',
                ['fk_owner_id' => $this->id],
                ['fk_owner_id2' => $this->id],
                ['fk_owner_id3' => $this->id]
            ])
            ->orderBy(Project::tableName().'.title')
            ->all();
```